# How to encode jsonb as part of an http response in golang

Tags: json, postgresql, go

I'm having a tough time moving json over the wire.

There is a `jsonb` field in a Postgres db that I need to add to a struct before sending it over the wire as an http response.

If the struct's payload field is a `string`, marshaling escapes the json like `"{\"id\": \"3aa5fff0-ad91-41b1-84f0-d97f38e0e0f4\", \"user\": 1 }`.

If the struct's payload field is a `json.RawMessage`, marshalling escapes the json as (what I imagine to be) a sequence of base64 encoded bytes.

This is the struct that I am marshaling and writing to the http response stream:

`` type NestJobReturn struct {
    Status string          `json:"status"`
    Nest   json.RawMessage `json:"nest"`
} ``

I build a `ret` instance of this struct and print it out. If I use `%v` it shows bytes, and `%s` shows it as the proper, un-escaped json string:

`log("Value of ret.Nest: %v", ret.Nest) // Value of ret.Nest: [123 34 105 ...
log("Value of ret.Nest as a string: %s", ret.Nest) // Value of ret.Nest as a string: {"id": "f053...`

Marshaling and i/o is done thusly:

`js, _ := json.Marshal(ret)
res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
res.Write(js)`

The client currently receives the entire message looking kinda like this:

`{"status":"ok","nest":"eyJpZCI6ICJmMD..."}`

... but the intended value of "nest" is the valid json from my `jsonb` column in the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte encodes as a base64-encoded string.`  `json.RawMessage` is []byte type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the nested field as a `pointer` to `json.RawMessage`, e.g.

```
type NestJobReturn struct {
    Status string           `json:"status"`
    Nest   *json.RawMessage `json:"nest"`
}

jsonStr := `{"type": "Object", "desc": "Simple nested object"}`
raw := json.RawMessage(jsonStr)

ret := NestJobReturn {
    Status: "DONE",
    Nest:   &raw,
}
```

A working example https://play.golang.org/p/Ju7kgbawss

Comment: This works, but [the RawMessage exmaple in the official docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage), doesn't use a pointer to the RawMessage, so I think it was designed to be used as a value.

Comment: Due to [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6528) and [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14493), I prefer to use `*json.RawMessage`. It gives the same JSON string when passing the container (`struct`) as `value` or `pointer` to `json.Marshal`. [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xeSaF9dXk9)

Comment: Thanks, those issue links are super awesome!  I understood why your fix worked, but I was having trouble wrapping my head around why mine did.  This clears things up a lot for me.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I've managed to work around the problem entirely in a different way that doesn't involve RawMessage. But this is good to know anyway, as I will likely need to do this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to marshal the pointer to your ret instead of the ret itself

simply change
`js, _ := json.Marshal(ret)`  to
`js, _ := json.Marshal(&ret)`

and it should start working.
[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/TwLHk_r1tv)

Better yet, you can make your struct idiot proof by either going with [I Putu Susila's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39652479/2012396) or replacing json.RawMessage with this very slightly tweaked version

```
type RawMessage []byte

// MarshalJSON returns m as the JSON encoding of m.
func (m RawMessage) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return m, nil
}

// UnmarshalJSON sets *m to a copy of data.
func (m *RawMessage) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if m == nil {
        return errors.New("json.RawMessage: UnmarshalJSON on nil pointer")
    }
    *m = append((*m)[0:0], data...)
    return nil
}
```

Then your struct will always Marshal itself correctly.
[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/PXOwf8W8Ol)

This is the fix that was suggested in [the github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14493#issuecomment-188407207) for this quirk (link courtesy of [I Putu Susila's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650479/how-to-encode-jsonb-as-part-of-an-http-response-in-golang/39652920#comment66610040_39652479)), but the consensus is that even though this is how RawMessage ought to behave, they can't change it now due to the go standard library's compatibility guarantee.  Fortunately, just because they couldn't fix it in the standard library doesn't mean you can't fix it in your own codebase.